# Cannot set global `include_path` in Quercus

Tags: php, quercus

I am unable to set persistent `php.ini`-style parameters in Quercus 4.0.36.

As an example, the `include_path` parameter can be set from code, either using `ini_set` or `set_include_path`, and the include path is updated. However, none of the documented ways of setting that parameter application-wide seem to work for me.

Any attempts to set an alternate `php.ini` location, or even `php.ini` settings directly from `web.xml` have been unsuccessful.

I've deployed `quercus-4.0.36.war` and either changed or uncommented the following lines from the original `web.inf`:

```xml
<web-app [...]>
    <servlet>
        [...]
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ini-file</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/php.ini</param-value>
        </init-param>
        [...]
        <init>
            <ini-file>WEB-INF/php.ini</ini-file>
        </init>
        [...]
        <init>
            <php-ini>
                <include_path>.:WEB-INF/classes</include_path>
            </php-ini>
        </init>
        [...]
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

Both `phpinfo` and `get_include_path`'s outputs are unaltered when setting any of the above parameters.

Is there anything else I should be doing in order to set `include_path` application- or system-wide?

Comment: This issue has also been reported [on Caucho's forums](http://forum.caucho.com/showthread.php?p=36987). If that gets any replies, I will update this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour was caused by [a bug](http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5448) that has been fixed for 4.0.37.