# In resin, using PHP the include_path directive is defaulted to /usr/share/php , even though I changed it?

Tags: php, linux, resin

Here's the line as I added it in php.ini

`include_path = "/usr/share/php/smarty:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/pear"`

I did `echo "Include Path: ". get_include_path();`

here's that output

`Include Path: .:/usr/share/php`

I confirmed it using `phpinfo()` for the correct php.ini, but the path is not being updated.

ed1: I even simplified the path to just 2 paths, still doesn't update. (I am restarting resin each time as well)

ed2: definitely the right file, if I change other settings and do a `echo ini_get('display_errors')` for instance, I can see it changes. So, what's up with the include path?

ed3: To make sure it's not a malformed uri or something, I used just 1 path, and it still doesn't work.

Thanks,

Comment: "I'm hoping I'm editing the correct php.ini file" --- what if you check `phpinfo()` to know for sure if it's the correct file?

Comment: I checked via `phpinfo()` to make sure.

Comment: so? Is it the correct file you're editing?

Comment: yes, it is the correct file. I'm just baffled why the change isn't being propagated.

Comment: it's not possible that you're modifying the correct file but changes are taken from somewhere else.

Comment: I assumed not, but I still don't know what's going on then. I'm way more familiar with Apache instead of Resin, so I don't know if there's some other directive taking over that I don't know about.

Comment: Maybe a `grep include_path /etc [relevant document roots]` could help.

Comment: Just the /etc/php5/cli (the one used) and the /etc/php5/apache2 (not used)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot set global \`include\_path\` in Quercus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860949/cannot-set-global-include-path-in-quercus)

Answer (score 0):

I found a duplicate question.

[Cannot set global `include_path` in Quercus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860949/cannot-set-global-include-path-in-quercus)

So I voted to close this as a duplicate. But I'll leave this here in case someone else stumbles on it.

Comment: I should note, the only reason I'm keeping it is because it's "In Resin" as opposed to Quercus, which I didn't realize ran PHP initially. So, maybe get people who searched as I did.